# How do I test a Typescript module with tsUnit and Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, typescript

Typescript 1.6.2, tsUnit 2.0.1, Node 5.4.1, OSX 10.11.2

I want to unit test functions in my Typescript `module` using [tsUnit](https://github.com/Steve-Fenton/tsUnit).  AFAIK, the [tsUnit examples](https://github.com/Steve-Fenton/tsUnit/tree/master/tsUnit.Node.Examples) only show how to test Typescript *classes* using Node.  The tsUnit Node example shows how to export the target class so it can be `require`d in the unit test.  Here's a simplified example:

**Foo.ts**

`class Foo{ ... }
export = Foo;`

**FooTest.ts**

`import Foo = require('../main/Foo');
var target = new Foo();`

I successfully unit tested a Typescript `class`, but not a `module`.
I tried two ways to test the module.  Both result in Typescript transpile errors.

**MyMod.ts**

**Approach 1:  Follow the pattern in the tsUnit `class` example.**

`module MyMod {...}
export = MyMod;`

Generates error:
`Error... TS2339: Property 'MyMod' does not exist on type 'typeof MyMod'.`

I don't know what this error means.  I couldn't find any applicable solution/explanation via Google or Stackoverflow.  Looking at the generated JavaScript code doesn't help me either.

**Approach 2: Export the module when it's declared.**

`export module MyMod {...}`

This makes the unit test happier, but in my application code, references to MyMod break.  Giving an error like this:

`Error... TS2304: Cannot find name 'MyMod'.`

---

How can I make MyMod functions available for unit testing, in a way that doesn't break my application calls to those functions?

[Most likely, I could use a JavaScript test framework for unit tests, but I prefer to use tsUnit if it's possible.]